# Which of the following statements about independent variables is correct?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Assume $z=x+y$, where $x$ and $y$ are the independent variables. Which of the following is true?

1. Since $x$ is independent of $y$, $\partial x/\partial y=0$.
2. $z=x+y$ can be solved for $x$; hence, $x=z-y$, which implies $\partial x/\partial y=-1$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, not to give anything away.... but note: Saying that $z= x+y$ can be "solved" for $x$ via $x=z-y$ is implying that $z$ is a constant, which it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that in the second statement you write $\partial x/\partial y=-1$ because $x=z-y$ and then $\partial x/\partial y=\partial (z-y)/\partial y$. Then you conclude that this is $0$ because you assume $z$ independent from $y$, but this is false, on the contrary, as $z=x+y$, $z$ depends from $y$ and  $\partial z/\partial y=1$, then $\partial x/\partial y=\partial (z-y)/\partial y=\partial z/\partial y-\partial y/\partial y=1-1=0$.